# R error in calculating AUC value from pROC package

Tags: r, roc, auc, proc-r-package

I am trying to use the `pROC` package in R to calculate sensitivity, specificity and threshold level. Here is a sample data

```
library(pROC)
x<-sample(0:1,7974,replace=T)
y<-sample(0:16049.2,7974,replace=T)
myroc<-roc(x,y)
coords(myroc, "best", ret=c("threshold", "sensitivity", "specificity"))

Error in UseMethod("coords") : 
 no applicable method for 'coords' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
```

Will anyone be able to tell me why this error is happening and how to fix it?

Thank you

Comment: I was able to copy and paste your code and it worked fine. I'm in R 3.2.4

Comment: can you print out your sessionInfo() and update your question ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I got it working. There was something wrong with R. I had to restart it and it started working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my best guess: the `roc` function name is used in several packages (11 on CRAN at the moment [according to the sos package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11379807/list-all-functions-on-cran)) and those will take precedence over `pROC` if they are loaded later in your session. By restarting R you cleared that function from your search path and are back to using pROC's `roc`.

To ensure you are using pROC's `roc` function, use the following syntax:

```
myroc<-pROC::roc(x,y)
```