# ROCR library prediction function error

Tags: atomic, prediction, roc

I am using ROCR library and the prediction function for creating ROC curves. I am doing like this (copied from Stack Overflow)

```
p_Lr <- predict(Model_Lr,newdata=Tst,type="response")
pr_Lr <- prediction(p_Lr, Tst$Survived)
prf_Lr <- performance(pr_Lr, measure = "tpr", x.measure = "fpr")
```

This works - in the beginning. Suddenly after programming and running various code (I am unfortunately not able to say precisely which code) the  line

```
pr_Lr <- prediction(p_Lr, Tst$Survived)
```

doesn't work any more and gives following error msg:

```
Error in nn$covariate : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors using rocr library prediction
```

Then if I detach and add the ROCR library like this

```
detach(package:ROCR)
library(ROCR)
```

it works again! Anybody have any idea why and what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [the sos findFn function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11379876/333599), it appears that two other packages have a function called `prediction`: [bootPLS](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/bootsPLS/html/prediction.html) and [frailtypack](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/frailtypack/html/prediction.html). Loading any of these packages after ROCR would mask ROCR's `prediction` function and prevent `performance` from working.

By re-attaching ROCR you put its `prediction` function back in front of the [search path](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html#search-path).

An alternative solution would be to use ROCR's `prediction` function explicitly:

```
p_Lr <- predict(Model_Lr,newdata=Tst,type="response")
pr_Lr <- ROCR::prediction(p_Lr, Tst$Survived)
prf_Lr <- ROCR::performance(pr_Lr, measure = "tpr", x.measure = "fpr")
```